# Redis Pub Sub channel memory

Tags: memory, redis, publish-subscribe

What mechanism(s) does Redis use to keep messages in memory in case of pub-sub ? If no client is subscribed what happens to the messages? Will Redis buffer them ? Is there a way to configure the min. and max. memory allocated per channel ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Redis does not keep messages in memory in the Pub/Sub context as you can see in the [implementation](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/b0f3922/src/pubsub.c#L218-L265) (x):

1. the message is sent to clients [listening for that channel](http://redis.io/commands/subscribe) (if any),
2. the message is sent to clients [listening to matching channels](http://redis.io/commands/psubscribe) (if any).

Then Redis simply returns how many clients have received the message (keeping in mind that a client may receive a single message multiple times e.g if multiple pattern matches).

If there is no client subscribed, Redis simply returns 0 and the message is not recorded/buffered:

```
> publish foo test
(integer) 0
```

*(x) basically Redis loops over the list of subscribed clients and sends a reply with the message.*