# What happens in Redis backstage?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I am using **Redis** with **Node Js** to share events between processes.

When I do a `pub.publish('...', 'message');` the other node processes are notified by a `sub.on('message', ...` event which is fine and it works ok.

Could someone please advise whether this Redis event/information is being stored/cached temporarily/permanently in memory. Do I have to delete this out of memory manualy ? Or does it automatically expires ? If so, when ?

I plan to publish a lot of small messages and instantly grab them but I am a little bit confused since I don't know exactly what is happening in the Redis backstage.

Comment: You can refer to this answer that quickly describes what happens behind the scenes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210754/redis-pub-sub-channel-memory/24219813#24219813

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pub/Sub messages are never being stored in memory, they are not treated as 'Data',
but just being delivered to the channel subscribers instantly.

Never mind deleting nor expiring them.